# I am writing a java program that uses one loop to process the integers from 300 down to 200

Tags: java

Here are my instructions:

Write a program that uses one loop to process the integers from 300 down to 200, inclusive. The program should detect multiples of 11 or 13, but not both. The multiples should be printed left-aligned in columns 8 characters wide, 5 multiples per line. When all multiples have been displayed, the program should display the number of multiples found and their sum.

```
int sum = 300;
while (sum >= 200 && sum <= 300 ) {
    sum = sum - 1;  
    System.out.println( sum % 11 == 0 || sum % 13 == 0 );
}
```

As you may know, I am getting `true` and `false` responses rather than the numbers. I am very much stuck and would like any help or advice I can get! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `==` operator is an equality operator that returns a condition (either `true` or `false`). That's why you're printing `true` and `false`. If you want to print the actual multiples, first check if they are either a multiple of 11 or a multiple of 13 (but not both), and then print the number, `sum`.

```
int sum = 300;
while (sum >= 200 && sum <= 300 ) {
    if((sum % 11 == 0) != (sum % 13 == 0)) { //checks if sum is a multiple of 11 or 13 but not both
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    sum = sum - 1;  
}
```

What `(sum % 11 == 0) != (sum % 13 == 0)` means is that if `sum` is a multiple of both 11 and 13, then the expression will equate to `false` because the results of `(sum % 11 == 0)` and `(sum % 13 == 0)` are both `true`. Similar reasoning will let you see that if `sum` is only a multiple of one of 11 or 13, then the expression will result in `true` since one side of the expression will result in `true` while the other side will result in `false`.

Comment: Do you know what the `^` operator is for? (Or `!=`, for that matter).

Comment: @AndyTurner are you saying I should replace `==` with `XNOR` and `!=` with `XOR`?

Comment: Nope. I mean that `(sum % 11 == 0) != (sum % 13 == 0)` would avoid the repetition.

Comment: Might want to add something about the formatting, to make the answer complete.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, just added an explanation!

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thank you for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework, I don't want to just give the answer away, but I'd like to help, so I'll give you a couple of hints:

1) "if" statements are where you'd want to use comparisons to decide what to do, e.g.

```
if (blah == more_blah)
```

2) Since your numbers are all guaranteed to be 3 characters, there is a simple and easy way to get the exact spacing of 8 characters per column. (Hint: `print()` and `println()` are both things)

3) Since you want multiple columns, you might want some way to check how many columns you have already and then decide whether you want println or print. (bonus hint: using `System.out.println("")` could make your code simpler.)